# Extract a Part of the String from Substring

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find the Regular expression to extract a part of my string from the Entire sub string .Feel free to suggest me a best Way .

so here is the case , i can get any Eamil  so lets say abd@gmail.com , or something similar ,
i want to remove just the Username that is "abd" and save into another string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll need regular expressions for that. Just do this:

```
NSString* email = @"abd@gmail.com";
NSArray * components = [email componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
NSString* username = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0];
```

you alsa can do:

```
NSString* email = @"abd@gmail.com";
NSString* username = [email substringToIndex:[email rangeOfString:@"@"].location];
```